# what is the fastest way to generate random ip numbers in c?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I need *fast* way to generate ip numbers that are valid (reserved ips are valid too).
For now i am using this:

```
unsigned char *p_ip;
unsigned long ul_dst;

p_ip = (unsigned char*) &ul_dst;
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(unsigned long);i++)
  *p_ip++ = rand()%255;
ip.sin_addr.s_addr = ul_dst;
```

But sometimes it generate non-valid numbers, but this code can generate about 10k of valid ips in a second. Can anyone contribute?
Thank you

Comment: Why does it generate invalid IP numbers?

Comment: well as i can think because unsigned long can hold value bigger than real ipv4 network space has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

calling rand() is probably the slowest part of your code, if you use the implementation of a random function found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry

This is an ultra fast C function for generating random numbers.

storing `sizeof(unsigned long)` in a registered variable i.e.:

`register int size = sizeof(unsigned long)`

should also help slightly.

Since you are using 4 chars = 4 x 8 byte memory, you can instead use a 32bit integer which will only require one memory address.
combining the bitshifting, new random method, registered variables, should reduce running times by quite a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

uint32_t ul_dst;
init_rand(time(NULL));
uint32_t random_num = rand_cmwc();

ul_dst = (random_num >> 24 & 0xFF) << 24 | 
         (random_num >> 16 & 0xFF) << 16 | 
         (random_num >> 8 & 0xFF) << 8 | 
         (random_num & 0xFF);

printf("%u\n",ul_dst);
return 0;
```

Above this code I have the exact copy of the random function from wikipedia.
Hopefully this will run much faster.
We know the size of a 32bit int is 4*8 so no need for the sizeof anymore, and instead of %255 I replaced it with a 255 bit mask

Comment: You are malloc()ing a four byte array. You are writing four 32 bit numbers into it.

Comment: Memleak you are not deleting `ul_dst`. I know the program terminates afterwards but still it's better to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! weird my compiler (or I) didn't pick it up.

Comment: `register` is ignored by any modern compiler.

Comment: I didn't look at the implementation, but wouldn't it be enough to call `init_rand()` only once per process? And when assigning the random value, wouldn't you need a bitmask like `((unsigned char*)ul_dst)[i] = (rand_cmwc() & 0xFF) << (i*8)`? Better yet, remove the for-loop altogether and get one random 32bit value. Every one if its Bits should be random (if the randomizer is any good), so interpreting that one number as four different ones should be just as random.

Comment: And yes, register is ignored and then effectively applied as the compiler sees fit ;)

Comment: Replacing the 4 by a 8 still does not make it fit.

Comment: Sorry all, you are correct, i think I need some coffee, I've opened this up to the public so you can update it.

Comment: Almost right. Make it "ul_dst = malloc( 4 * sizeof \*ul_dst);". You don't want the cast; malloc() returns void*.

Comment: @Serdalis, thanks for your code, i too tryed wikipedias code and it achive +4-5k more ips per second, but the another thing is still ip's can be non-valid, because unsigned long s_addr can hold more than ipv4 space. also why you call init_rand so many times? should it not called once ?

Comment: I blame tiredness, yes calling it once then splitting the return value into 8 bit chunks using bit shifting with a bit mask will both modular (bitmask) and create a full 32 bit number, which would be the fastest method. Which I have edited in now.

Comment: @Serdalis: Wouldn't your transformation always lead to `ul_dst == random_num`?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code writes four chars to memory. You can optimize this by writing one int32 to memory.

Comment: well i just need to write random number generator for this purpose or what? libc rand() returns only int value

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own random generator. For this purpose anything with a period of (1<<32) is valid, so you could construct a lineair congruential thing. (you would not need to construct from 4 separate characters, too)

Also, your *p_ip is uninitialised. you probably want a

```
p_ip = (unsigned char *) &ul_dst;
```

somewhere.

Comment: yes, i just manually write the code from my editor and forget about line where it is initialized, can you please descriebe in detail about "anything with a period of (1<<32) is valid"

Comment: "Roll your own random generator. " - that is usually not a good idea. Use a well known one that's been tested.

Comment: I presume you want (eventually) every possible 32 bit number to occur in the output. Starting with any number, and repeatingly adding a constant (relatively prime to (1<<32)) will do that. You still have to check for invalid IP-addresses and reserved ranges, of course.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I don't think he wants random. He just wants all the IP addresses in some seemingly random order. But I agree with you: this is exactly how the sasser-worm failed ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser as i can understand you mean just increasing ip integer value, but i need really random ip's. or if i in error please can you demonstrate basic code?

Comment: @wildplasser haha well the randomness of targets is virus-owners fault when they decide on rand() not fully read the manual ;p

Comment: @Segey: please rephrase your question. Do you really want random IP-adresses ? How random should they be ? Do you allow duplicates ? What do you need them for ?

Comment: @wildplasser i need random ip numbers generated in manner: next ip addr not in network of previous ip addr, so theyre random. about duplicates i am cheking it with vector<unsigned long>, but i found duplicates generated in about 2-3 times in a second so i just turnoff duplicate check because its code takes some time and in this case this is not needed. I am writing project scanning entire ipv4 space for some open ports, especially now i am investigating honeypot presence in entire ipv4 space. the code runs on (now) 2 boxes in different locs but uses one database. i use pthread/mysql/ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

Building over @Serdalis idea of using init_rand(), maybe you can try something I had come across called Knuth Shuffle which will help you generate Random Numbers with a uniform Distribution.

The code will look like this I guess now but the below example uses rand():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define TOTAL_VAL_COUNT 254
int byteval_array[TOTAL_VAL_COUNT] = {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
   11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
   21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
   31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
   41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
   51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
   61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70,
   71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
   81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90,
   91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100,
   101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110,
   111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120,
   121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130,
   131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140,
   141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150,
   151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160,
   161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170,
   171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180,
   181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190,
   191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200,
   201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210,
   211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,
   221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230,
   231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240,
   241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250,
   251, 252, 253, 254
};


unsigned char denominator = TOTAL_VAL_COUNT+1;

unsigned char generate_byte_val();  
unsigned char generate_byte_val() { 
    unsigned char inx, random_val;

    if (denominator == 1)
            denominator =  TOTAL_VAL_COUNT+1;
    inx = rand() % denominator; 
    random_val = byteval_array[inx];
    byteval_array[inx] = byteval_array[--denominator];
    byteval_array[denominator] = random_val;
    return random_val;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    int i;
    struct in_addr ip;
    for (i = 1; i < 255; ++i)  {
        ip.s_addr = (generate_byte_val() |
                    (generate_byte_val() << 8) |
                    (generate_byte_val() << 16) |
                    (generate_byte_val() << 24));
            printf ("IP = %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip));
    }
}
```

HTH